# Nordström's Second Theory of Gravity, and Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, quantum-gravity

I read about [Nordström's Theory of Gravitation][1]

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordstr%C3%B6m%27s_theory_of_gravitation and how it was proposed before General Relativity.  There were two Nordström Theories of Gravitation, but I will be asking specifically about the second.  The field Equations for Nordström's Theory of Gravitation are $$R=24{\pi}T$$ $$C_{abcd}=0$$

Nordström's Theory of Gravitation describes Gravity as being spacetime curvature, and is also self consistent.

Some of the ways that Nordström's Theory of Gravitation disagree with GR is that it predicts that there should be no gravitational lensing, and from looking at the equation for the metric it looks like it also predicts that there should be no black holes.  Also it looks like in Nordström's Theory of Gravitation there is no singularity even in the case of a point mass.
Nordström's Theory of Gravitation also makes different predictions than GR when it comes to Mercuries Orbit.

So Nordström's Theory of Gravitation doesn't describe our universe as it's predictions disagree with observations and measurements.  I understand that General Relativity and Quantum Mechanics currently contradict each other, and in cases, in which quantum physics is needed, gravity is negligible.

My question is, is Nordström's Second Theory of Gravitation is just as inconsistent with Quantum Mechanics as GR or if it's easier to combine Nordström's Theory of Gravitation with Quantum Mechanics?  If it is easier, then what does a quantum version of Nordström's Theory of Gravitation look like?